# Why is the Quanteda package extremely slow on a MacOS Venture M2?

Tags: r, quanteda

When I run the `tokens` `Quanteda` function on a MacOS Venture M2 10-core 16 GB RAM 512 GB, this function is extremely slow.

For example, for a corpus with only one text document it takes 0.08 seconds, for a corpus with 5 text documents it already takes 3 seconds and for a corpus with 10 text documents it takes 20 seconds and so on... This is extremely slow compared to various other devices and other operating systems my colleagues have in use.

Just as a benchmark:
We can run the `tokens` function with a corpus with over 2000 documents in less than 50 seconds on a Windows laptop with an intel i3 (8th generation) and 4 GB RAM.

Why does the package/function run so extremely slowly on this device?Is there any way to solve this problem?
I use the following versions of
R(R-4.2.3; aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)),
RStudio (latest version),
the `Quanteda` package (latest version) (and the latest versions of all dependent packages),
Xcod (CLI) (Version 14.3 ),
XQuartz-2.8.5
and
gfortran (gfortran-ARM-12.2-Ventura). In addition, I installed xz-utils and PCRE2 with Homebrew.

Comment: Hi, please refrain from boldfacing.

Comment: Look up the "r-sig-mac" mailing list archives, as there has been a lot of discussion about the M1 and M2 chips' performance.   I recommend you join the list:   r-sig-mac@r-project.org   ;   r-sig-mac-request@r-project.org